# How to use a class like a field in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity

Is there a way to use a class to store a simple value in Entity Framework.

I want to create a class to store a simple `int32` value and name it as `ID`.

And use it simply in Entity Framework, but I want the inner `int32` value be saved in the database not to create another table to store the ID class and create a relation between these two tables (the user of ID and ID itself).

Let me explain in codes:

```
public class ID
{
    public int InnerID { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClassName
{
    public ID id { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    //....
}
```

I want the result be like:

```
-------------------
| InnerID  | Age  |
-------------------
| val1     | val1 |
```

`InnerID` created as field not a reference to ID's table.

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't use a class as key, if that's what you mean. (Except `String`)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely you can do that with EF. These are referred to, in EF, as complex types. But the important thing is that a complex type does not have an entity key then EF will know to map it to fields in the same table as the "host" class (e.g. SomeClassName). Here's MSDN doc on Complext Types in E: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738472(v=vs.100).aspx

Alternatively, for this particular scenario, you might want to make your "ID" class a base class (abstract) and then SomeClassName could drive from it. I've changed it's name though to identity. ID is confusing to me.

```
    public abstract class Identity {
         public int InnerID { get; set; } 
     }

     public class SomeClassName:Identity {
          public int Age { get; set; }
        //.... 
     }
```

Comment: thank u but, this is not what I wanted, I want Identity itself as field in code but EF save the InnerID for me.

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: okay so the base class (2nd idea) is not the path. Check the complex type documentation (1st idea) to see if that works for you.